# Filter table when search box is in a template view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following structure

```
<div ng-include src="'_TableSearch.html'"></div>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="personin people | filter:searchQeury">                
            <td><span>{{person.name}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The ng-include template is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search.." ng-model="searchQeury" />
```

The problem,

I cant seem to get the filter to work. When the html that is currently in the template, is directly inserted above the table definition, it works.

I can't seem to fine what the issue is.

Comment: It doesn't work because `searchQuery` exists in the parent scope. try using `$parent.searchQuery` in the filter

Comment: Thanks so much. That solved my problem. I understand this process now. Thanks again.